# using random in class to make a loop

Tags: c++, class, loops

I want to ask user to set a compass direction as a char, using n for north, e for east etc and so on, or to use default value which is set to North.  e.g (0,0,'n').

Then I want to make it randomly move 100 times in any direction. **I am now confused on the loop inside my class. I don't know where should I add the loop**. Also, the output shows me the values I have typed.

I would appreciate your help !

output example:

0===0---n

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

class bug
{
public:
    bug();
    bug(int x_pos, int y_pos, char direction);
    void turn(char direction);
    void move(int x, int y,char direction);
    int get_X() const;
    int get_Y() const;
    char get_direction() const;

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    char direction;
};

bug::bug(int x_pos, int y_pos, char d)
{
    x = x_pos;
    y = y_pos;
    direction = d;
}

bug::bug()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    direction = 'n';
}

void bug::turn(char direction)
{
    int num = 1 + rand() % 3;
    if (direction == 'n')
    {
        if (num == 1)
            direction = 'e';
        else if (num == 2)
            direction = 'w';
        else if (num == 3)
            direction = 'n';
    }
    else if (direction == 'w')
    {
        if (num == 1)
            direction = 'w';
        else if (num == 2)
            direction = 'n';
        else if (num == 3)
            direction = 's';
    }
    else if (direction == 's')
    {
        if (num == 1)
            direction = 's';
        else if (num == 2)
            direction = 'w';
        else if (num == 3)
            direction = 'e';
    }
    else if (direction == 'e')
    {
        if (num == 1)
            direction = 'e';
        else if (num == 2)
            direction = 'n';
        else if (num == 3)
            direction = 's';
    }
}

void bug::move(int x, int y, char direction)
{
    if (direction == 'n')
            y = y + 1;
    else if (direction == 'w')
        x = x - 1;
    else if (direction == 's')
        y = y - 1;
    else if (direction == 'e')
        x = x + 1;
}

int bug::get_X() const
{
    return x;
}

int bug::get_Y() const
{
        return y;
}

char bug::get_direction() const
{
    return direction;
}

void display(bug start)
{
    cout << start.get_X()<<"==="<<start.get_Y()  << "---"<<start.get_direction() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    bug first;
    int choice;
    cout << custom mode(1) or default mode(2) ?  ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        int x, y;
        char dir;
        cout << "the x axis: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "the y axis: ";
        cin >> y;
        cout << "the direction: ";
        cin >> dir;

        bug first(x, y, dir);
        //first.turn(dir);
        //first.move(x,y);
        display(first);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j =0;j<100;j++)
        {
            bug first;
            //first.turn;
            //first.move();
            //for(int j =0;j<100;j++)
            display(first);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: There is no input checking for things like entering a three for the mode or something other than the lower case letters for south, north, west, or east.  Is this temporary until the location for the 100 random moves loop is determined?

Comment: Do you want the bug to make the random walk only if the user chooses 2 (the default mode), or in either case? Do you know how to choose a direction at random? Do you want the walk to be a member function, or do you want `main` to call `move` 100 times?

Comment: On the movement itself, are there upper and lower limits for x and y?  For example is this strictly a screen location that can never be lower than `(0,0)` and never higher than something like `(1440, 900)`?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: _italic_ **yes, it is .  I want it make the random walk in both cases ** `code`

Comment: Also, i was trying to add random function inside the void get_direction function, which is num=1+rand()%3.  the coordinate does not need the limit. it can be negative.

Comment: Having a random generator inside a differently named method is better.  For example, leave the existing get methods as they are and create `getRandDirection`, `getRandX`, and `getRandY` methods to have random support.  It all depends on the design decisions.

Comment: So you mean that I make above function which create a random variable and pass the value to my void function ?    at the same time,for example, i want the bug move step by step, which i have to use previous random direction to generate the other random direction. should i make the other function for this?

Comment: The best approach is to think through and understand the requirements, implement the simple aspects, confirm the actual behavior to the expected by running through the debugger and recording results, analyze the results and compare to the expected results, determine modifications, implement them, repeat until the actual behaviors matches all of the expected behaviors.  Since you are the only one who knows what the final behaviors should be, only you can decide which way to implement these new random features.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `"` on the line:

```
cout << custom mode(1) or default mode(2) ?  ";
```

I believe the intention is to have the double quote in front of the word `custom` like so:

```
cout << "custom mode(1) or default mode(2) ?  ";
```

**Start Modification** 
There are some things to consider that will be more clearly seen by stepping through with the debugger and observing the internal variables versus the passed by value parameters.  The passed by value parameters happen to be named the same as the internal class data member variables.  Please think through these things and decide what the desired behavior is for the `turn` and `move` functions for both `mode choices`. 
**End Modification**